2003 Chevrolet Silverado turn the ignition makes a click like a bad connection turn ignition off then turn ignition again and it starts
Put on a new starter, alternator, has new battery but when you turn the ignition it clicks kinda like it's not getting a connection,then turn the ignition again and it starts what can cause this problem

Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! When you say it clicks, do you hear a rapid succession of clicks or just a single click and nothing? The dash and light still light up when you turn the key no matter if it starts or clicks?
